# What is the Java-compatibile equivalent in Scala for <? extends Foo>

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I have a java class "JavaClass" with a method:

```
boolean addAll(java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.Integer> collection) { ... }
```

I need to create a Scala trait MyTrait that includes this method without an implementation, something like

```
def addAll[A<:java.lang.Integer](coll: java.util.Collection[A]) : Boolean
```

so that an implementation

```
class MyClass extends JavaClass with MyTrait
```

would not be abstract.  But I can't figure out any way to match the Java signature in Trait.

FWIW... I'm trying to write some high-performance Scala-collection-compatible wrappers for [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), which avoids generics to provide high performance with primitives, but used highly consistent interfaces for each primitive type.  I've found that in general, traits work well to model the type-independent demi-interfaces, but I can't figure out how to express this particular signature - even ignoring, for the moment, the type-abstraction I'm using the trait for.

Comment: The motivation is almost always worth getting into!

Comment: @RandallSchulz Ok, you asked for it ;-) - see updated post.

Comment: I've used Trove. Scala's answer to this is known as *specialization*, in which the `@specialized` annotation is used to tell the compiler to create separate overloads of the target entity for each of the specified primitive types.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I've read in several places that it's impossible, or nearly so, to meaningfully @@specialize the Scala collection implementations - one always ends up boxing, regardless.  So I'm starting from a different place, and seeing if I get anywhere.  If nothing else, I'll learn a lot along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collection<? extends java.lang.Integer>` in java is equivalent to

```
Collection[T] forSome {type T <: java.lang.Integer}
```

or using placeholder syntax `Collection[_ <: java.lang.Integer]` 
in scala