# Java Wildcard Generic Type Interop From Scala

Tags: scala

I'm writing in scala and I'm dealing with a Java API which returns a 
`List<? extends IResource>`, where `IResource` is a generic parent interface ([the details, if it helps](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/hapi-fhir-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/model/api/IResource.java)).

I'm trying to add an `IResource` to the list returned by that method, but I can't get my code to compile (`Patient` [is a java class which implements](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/1adfc4b4d963159ac01fe0aae036424200912823/hapi-fhir-structures-dstu/src/test/java/ca/uhn/fhir/testmodel/Patient.java) `IResource`, and [getContainedResources](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/hapi-fhir-base/src/main/java/ca/uhn/fhir/model/base/composite/BaseContainedDt.java) returns the `List<? extends IResource>`):

Here is my original code

```
val patient = new Patient()
patient.setId(ID)
val patientASResource: IResource = patient
entry.getResource.getContained.getContainedResources.add(patient)
```

And here is the error I get:

```
type mismatch;
  found   : patientASResource.type (with underlying type ca.uhn.fhir.model.api.IResource)
  required: ?0 where type ?0 <: ca.uhn.fhir.model.api.IResource
         entry.getResource.getContained.getContainedResources.add(patientASResource)
                                                                  ^
 one error found
```

Notice that I'm trying to add `patientASResource` which I've typed-up to the interface `IResource`. Trying to add `patient` (the class implementing the interface) has a worse error message.

Other things I've tried:

```
//From what I understand of "Java wildcards" per here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21805492/2741287
type Col = java.util.Collection[_ <: IResource]
val resList: Col = entry.getResource.getContained.getContainedResources
val lst: Col = asJavaCollection(List(patient))
resList.addAll(lst)
```

Doesn't work either, it returns something like:

```
type mismatch
found : java.util.Collection[_$1(in method transformUserBGs)] where type _$1(in method transformUserBGs) <: ca.uhn.fhir.model.api.IResource 
 required: java.util.Collection[_ <: _$1(in type Col)]
 resList.addAll(lst)
 ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with interop. This definitely shouldn't compile, and neither should the equivalent Java code.

`List<? extends IResource>` means it can be a `List<IResource>`, `List<Patient>`, `List<SomeSubclassOfPatient>`, `List<SomeOtherResourceUnrelatedToPatient>`, etc. and you don't know which. Thus, adding a `Patient` (or an `IResource` after upcasting) to such a list is not allowed.

If you somehow know that in your specific situation `entry` is such that `entry.getResource.getContained.getContainedResources` returns a `List[IResource]`, or a `List[Patient]`, you should attempt to ensure this statically by specifying this when overriding `getContainedResources`. If this is impossible, the last recourse is to cast:

```
entry.getResource.getContained.
  getContainedResources.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[IResource]].add(patient)
```

Just to reiterate: you should avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks your comments helped me realize my problem, which was that I didn't understand Existential types/java's wildcards.